# See which table has affected another table SQL-Server

Tags: php, html, sql-server, database

I have created a program in which a user will enter what device they are using and will then perform a task to test their performance based on the device they are using. The user will be taken to a start page in which they will type what device they are using, select from a drop down what hand they are using and the screen width and height will be collected via Javascript along with a primary key called DeviceID. So far all this data is stored in my first table. The second table contains data relating to the user performance such as time etc.

The first table has a one-to-many relationship with the second table as for every 1 device there will be approximately be 100 results.

The part which I am struggling with however is being able to recognise which device entered has gotten which results (i.e. DeviceID 1 got these results, DeviceID 2 got those results etc) and how I can view this relationship.

Edit:
**First PHP Page**

```
<?php
include 'db.php';

    $screenWidth = $_POST['screenWidth'];
    $screenHeight = $_POST['screenHeight'];
        $HandUsed = $_POST['HandUsed'];

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{ 
    $screenWidth = $_POST['screenWidth'];
    $screenHeight = $_POST['screenHeight'];
    $phoneType = $_POST['phoneName'];
    $HandUsed = $_POST['HandUsed'];


    echo 'hello';


   $sql = "INSERT INTO deviceInfo (screenWidth, phoneType, screenHeight, HandUsed)
     VALUES ('$screenWidth','$phoneType', '$screenHeight', '$HandUsed')";

     if (sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql)) {
       // echo "New record has been added successfully !";
     } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . ":-" . sqlsrv_errors($conn);
     }
     sqlsrv_close($conn);
}
```

**Second PHP Page**

```
<?php
include 'db.php';

    $Xpos = $_POST['Xpos'];
    $Ypos = $_POST['Ypos'];
    $StartID = $_POST['StartID'];
    $Random = $_POST['RandomID'];
    $Time = $_POST['timeTaken'];


     $sql = "INSERT INTO UserResults6(Xpos, Ypos, StartID, RandomID, TimeTaken, DeviceID)
     VALUES ('$Xpos', '$Ypos', '$StartID', '$Random', '$Time', SELECT DeviceID from deviceInfo)";


     if (sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "New record has been added successfully !";
     } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . ":-" . sqlsrv_errors($conn);
     }
     sqlsrv_close($conn);

?>
```

In the first page everything works as intended and I am given the information that I want along with an auto-incremented DeviceID. In the first page everything works up until the select statement to get the DeviceID. The outcome that I would be hoping for would be for the DeviceID to match with DeviceID from the prior table but I am currently unsure of how to go about achieving this.

Comment: Please show your table strictures and some sample data. Also your expected output from them will help more,

Comment: Hi I've made some edits just there with some of the code.